# Play Framework with Neo4j-Anormcypher

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, neo4j

I want to include the AnormCypher of Neo4j library to my playframework project in Eclipse but I stuck.I'am using Windows 8.These are few steps that I am doing;

- Creating a project from CMD(CommandPrompt) "play new testproject"
- Creating project files for Eclipse "testproject eclipse"
- As it mentioned this link : [AnormCypher](https://github.com/AnormCypher/AnormCypher)
  I'am creating a build.sbt file then I run "play compile".

After all in eclipse I can't reach the org.AnorCypher library.I couldnt find the way to add it.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or what do you mean?

Comment: Just guessing, but, did you re-ran the eclipse command after adding the deps in build.sbt? (note: you could also have added it to your Build.scala file)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and i didnt use build.sbt,just edited the Build.scala file and ran the "play compile" command in CMD.

Build.scala:

```
  import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "project1"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm

  )

   val Repos = Seq(
    "anormcypher" at "http://repo.anormcypher.org/",
    "Mandubian repository snapshots" at "https://github.com/mandubian/mandubian-mvn/raw/master/snapshots/",
    "Mandubian repository releases" at "https://github.com/mandubian/mandubian-mvn/raw/master/releases/"
  )


  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here  


        resolvers ++= Repos,
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                "play"        %% "play-json" % "2.2-SNAPSHOT",
                "org.anormcypher" %% "anormcypher" % "0.4.0"

              )    
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions on Github, "play compile" and re-run "play eclipse" command. Here's my build.sbt:

```
name := "myprojectname"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "anormcypher" at "http://repo.anormcypher.org/",
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "org.anormcypher" %% "anormcypher" % "0.4.4"
)     
play.Project.playScalaSettings
```